# How to read and print an integer?

Tags: mips, qtspim

This code keeps printing 1 no matter what I type and I do not know why.

```
.text
    .globl __start
__start:

li $v0,5
syscall         # read number

li $v0,1
syscall                 #print number

li $v0, 10
syscall

.data
```

Comment: I suggest that you read the documentation for system calls 1 and 5 again, and pay special attention to what it says regarding arguments and results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code so it works properly
if you are using mars you can go to help tab it will show you a list of syscalls and how they are used.

- 5 calls for user input
- 1 prints integer / float
- you need to put $a0 register with so it can print it move instruction is used

.text
.globl __start
__start:

li $v0,5
syscall         # read number

move $t0, $v0  #temp register can use $a0 if you want here

li $v0,1
move $a0, $t0       #a0 is used for syscall as an argument going in to be printed in this case
syscall                 #print number

li $v0, 10
syscall

.data